# How to go to previous line in CSV file?

Tags: c++

```
while (!fin.eof())
{
    getline(fin,line);
    stringstream s(line);
    
    while (getline(s, word, ','))
    {
        row.push_back(word);
    }

    if (RowFound(row))
    {
        fin << "Pass";
    }
}
```

The problem is that the word "Pass" is deleting chars from next line,
so my question is how can I move the cursor to beginning of line?

Comment: You also have [`tellg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) and [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)

Comment: Fyi, standard warning: [`while (!fin.eof())` is nearly always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score -1):

You can store the current position of the file using [`tellg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg), and then go back to that position using [`seekg(...)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)

Details [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-record-from-a-file-in-c-using-seekg-and-tellg/#:%7E:text=in%20C%2B%2B%20STL-,Read%20a%20record%20from%20a%20File%20in,seekg()%20and%20tellg()&text=The%20tellg()%20function%20is,the%20pointer%20in%20the%20stream.)

Comment: I'd be careful about linking to geekforgeeks. The example they provide uses `#include <bits/stdio.h>` which is not a standard header file.